# Why isn't my 'cycle' script running?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script called jquery.cycle.js that cycles through images. I'm trying to use it with wordpress and have it included and running correctly, but the following code works on this page http://violapark.com/ and not this one http://polygoats.com/wordpress/

Check out the dev panel to see, but this code throws an error, as if the script isn't included:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.slideshow').cycle({
                fx: 'fade',
                timeout: 2000,
                delay: -1000
            });
        });
```

Comment: Did you include the cycle.js file? (or whatever it's named)

Comment: yeah he has included that `jQuery Cycle Plugin`

Comment: this still isn't working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are including jquery a second time, after your script.

What is happening is that jquery is loaded, then your script modifies the object, then you load jquery from a different source which destroys the changes you made to the original object.

In your header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://polygoats.com/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2"></script>
```

Later in your body:

```
<script src="jquery.cycle.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script> <!-- destroys your changes -->
```

If you remove that second include it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Also include Jquery.min.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

before your `cycle.js`

**Wordpress** has already Jquery Loaded so you can remove your `jQuery.js` from your script and try ..I suppose its mere Jquery Conflict

Comment: I think he's including jquery.js AFTER cycle.js, so while jQuery is there you might be right about the before part.

Comment: it only works with the jquery tag included. moving it underneath the cycle script only throws a different error